# How can I prove mathematically that $(u+v+w)/3$ represents the centroid of the triangle formed by these vectors?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Given $u ,v, w$ vector in different directions.

I can do it using a cad software.

Comment: Just check it satisfies all the conditions of a centroid.

Comment: Both are affine invariants, and it's true (by symmetry) for equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=\frac{u+v+w}3$. The position vector of the mid-point of side $vw$ is $m=\frac{v+w}2$. It is easy to see that $u,m,C$ are colinear: $C-u\|m-u$. Thus $C$ lies on the median from $u$ to side $vw$. In a similar fashion you can show $C$ lies on the other medians.

Comment: Thanks and Since, u is a vertex, m-u is one of the bisectors of triangle. we can also show 2(m-u)/3 =(C-u), ie: the centroid divides the bisectors into 2:1 ratio.

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH Yup, you can use that argument also.